# Visual Studio forcing me to use full namespace even with reference added and "using" added

Tags: c#, excel, office-automation

Im using VS2013 community copying and I have downloaded the excel library and it still forces me to write the whole namespace each time saying it cant distinguish between winforms.application() and excel.application. It also says that the "missing" in "missing.value" does not have context.

This code is copied almost entirely from the MS website.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace ExcelAuto 
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Initiate Excel Objects

            //XlMSApplication oXL;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application oXL;
            Workbook oWB;
            Worksheet oSheet;
            Range oRng;

            try
            {
                //Start Excel and get Application Object.
                oXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                oXL.Visible = true;

                //Get a new workbook
                oWB= (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook)(oXL.Workbooks.Add(Missing.Value));

            }
            catch { }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps it cannot resolve because another class with that name is causing ambiguity? This happens with OpenTK, too, because some of the enum classes math the .Net System.Drawing namespace have the same name.

Comment: As mentioned, it is an issue of ambiguity.  If you don't like having the full namespace in your code, you can always use an alias.     https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx

Comment: Yes, as it turns out; more than one person decided to create an "Application" class, and you need to tell it which specific one to use.

Comment: @EricPhillips Thank you so much! That really helped alot that makes the code so much more legible for me. I just need to figure out now why it says missing.value has no context

Comment: just be cautious not to obsfucate your code with over alias-ing, another developer may be disoriented when they are expecting `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()` and they come across `BreakMyFast.SpreadsheetStuff.Application()`  .  They might assume that is custom code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because you are using the `Application` class which is present in two namespaces: `System.Windows.Forms` and `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`. Fully qualified name allows to determine which one has to be used.

Comment: And what about the Missing.Value having no context? It's being used the exact way the example used it.

Comment: NVM! I got it you have to add "using System.Reflection" in order for it to work.

Comment: I instinctively hit Ctrl + . on any squiggly line in Visual Studio. It will show you suggested solutions for an issue. If a using is missing VS will ask you if you want it added.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the class name was colliding with a namespace name, which made it a bit less obvious as my IDE was suggesting there was only 1 class with that name.